# How to install postgresl 9.6.8 or 10.3 to Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark?

Tags: apt, repository, postgresql

There is this postgres security patch which was deployed at heroku and now I can't install postgres dumps from heroku to my local machine. Because this masterminds able to produce only archived dumps not plain sql.
Ubuntu 17.10 is not supported by postgres and `aptitude` failed to install 10.3 version from Xenial repos.

[Getting "unsupported version (1.13) in file header" when running pg_restore | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064209/getting-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-when-running-pg-r)

Comment: I believe the `postgresql` package in the official 17.10 repositories installs 9.6.8. Have you tried `sudo apt install postgresql`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upgrade from 10.1 to 10.3 by changing to the xenial repository at https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/.

Comment: That worked to upgrade all the client programs (pg_dump, pg_restore, psql), but it does not allow the server to be upgraded.  To do that, you have to add "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list".  (The libicu55 package is required for PG 10.3 server, and it is not available on Artful.) Once you add this, do an "sudo apt update" and the package will be upgradable.